# Google classroom api: Keep getting 400 invalid argument

Tags: google-apis-explorer, google-classroom

I am testing the google classroom api using the google playground environment.  Everytime I make a post request to this endpoint: https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses, I keep getting this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", 
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.", 
    "code": 400
  }
}
```

This is my POST body that I am sending to the endpoint:

```
{
  "id": "1234T",
  "name": "Physics 101",
  "section": "Period 2",
  "room": "101",
  "ownerId": "me"
}
```

I am passing all of the necessary items such as Bearer token, etc. and as far as I can tell I am also passing the necessary fields in the json body. What is causing this error and how can I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was with the id field being in the json object.  Once I removed this, it started working.  The doc at the following link seemed like you could create an id as an alias, still a little confused on that process, but here is the link: https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses#Course.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, the id alias must begin with "p:" or "g:", indicating its visibility. Doing this you won't receive that error.